# populate text field(s), in a form, based on dynamic drop box.

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I would like to thank you in advance for taking the time out to help me, as I am really stuck.

I have two tables. Employee (Employee_ID, First_name, Last_name, Address etc) and Training (Training_ID, Employee_ID, First_name, Last_name, Training_type).

For the training table, i have a form in which is meant to be filled out to assign a training type for an employee.

What I want in my form is to have a drop down box, named select employee_ID, where it has the values of the employee_ID's in the employee table, it is a foreign key from that table.

AND once a selection has been chosen, i would like two text fields to be updated in the form, First name and Last name.

I am having many problems trying to implement a code which can do this, i dont know whether i should add java or not. i will show my basic code below to show you what it looks like now.

html form

```
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
<title>Training</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="content">  
<h1 align="center">Add Training</h1>

<form action="inserttraining.php" method="post">
<div>
<p>Training ID: <input type="text" name="Training_ID"></p>
<p>Employee ID: <input type="text" name="Employee_ID"></p>
<p>First name: <input type="text" name="First_name"></p>
<p>Last name: <input type="text" name="Last_name"></p>
<p>
Training required?
<select name="Training">
<option value="">Select...</option>
<option value="Customer Service">Customer Service</option>
<option value="Bailer">Bailer</option>
<option value="Reception">Reception</option>
<option value="Fish & meat counters">Fish & meat counters</option>
<option value="Cheese counters">Cheese counters</option>
</select>
</p>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and my php code which stores the data into the DB.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("hrmwaitrose", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO training (Training_ID, Employee_ID, First_name, Last_name, Training)
VALUES
('$_POST[Training_ID]','$_POST[Employee_ID]','$_POST[First_name]','$_POST[Last_name]','$_PO    ST[Training]')";


if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

AS i said above THANKS IN ADVANCE, this is killing me.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think you have some data duplication in your database. As you're using the foreign key in the Training table, you don't need to also store the employee's first and last name, as that information is in the Employee table. Data duplication is generally a bad idea because it can allow inconsistencies in your data.

To solve your problem, you would first need to populate the drop-down list with Employee_ID numbers in your HTML form. For simplicity I recommend that you change that page to be a PHP page, and add the following code to replace your Employee_ID text box.

```
<select id="Employee_ID">
<?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT Employee_ID FROM Employee");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
        echo "<option value=$row[0]>$row[0]</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
```

Then you will need to implement some AJAX in order to fill the text boxes with the Employee's name. You can do this by writing some Javascript that handles the `onChange` event of a drop-down list. This Javascript will then need to send a request to a PHP page to get the corresponding `First_Name` and `Last_Name` for a particular `Employee_ID`.

Comment: sorry as a newbie I am ABIT confused with what you saying. the code you have just sent me, where should i insert it? I would like there to be a drop down box for employee ID where i will be able to acces the IDS stored in the database, THANKS FOR YOU HELP

Comment: The above code should go in your form to replace your Employee_ID text box.

Comment: for some reason it does not work. a drop box is formed but it is really small, and no options appear from the drop down box

Comment: You need to have also connected to your database first.